# getting data from arduino to a database(mysql or any)

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I would like your help on these. Does anyone know how to get data from arduino to a database? Specifically mysql or any other database that we can use.

Comment: What have you tried?  There are lots of Arduino tutorials.  It will be easier to help you if you show your code, and tell how it doesn't work

Comment: Well i havent started yet. Im looking for the best option to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need a backend on your server. The Arduino calls a php script with POST or GET Parameters and the php script writes the content to your database. 
Add some HTTP Basic Auth and the job is done,

Comment: Thanks appreciate it alot